# Tesseract OCR with C# regular expressions

Tags: c#, ocr, tesseract

I use C# with Tesseract Library for recognition temperature value from webcam, that get video stream from Infrared Thermal Imager Screen. I use Tesseract parameter `tessedit_char_whitelist` and get not bad result, but it's would be improved.

Is it possible to use something like Reg Expression in Tesseract?

In my case, the first digit is always 3 or 4. Then any digit, the separator of the integer and fractional parts "." and any number. There are only 4 signs to recognize. The color and size of the characters does not change.  However, the background may change and highlight the numbers if a warm object hits the place where the numbers are displayed.

```cs
Tesseract.Rect rCurr = new Tesseract.Rect(x1, y1, w1, h1);
Tesseract.Rect rMax = new Tesseract.Rect(x2, y2, w2, h2);

using (var ocr = new TesseractEngine(@"./tessdata", "eng", EngineMode.TesseractOnly))
{
    ocr.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "0123456789.");
    //ocr.SetVariable("editor_image_text_color", "white");

    Bitmap bitMapInput = _imageInput.ToBitmap(); 
    Bitmap bitMapOutput = _imageOutput.ToBitmap();

    var imgIn = PixConverter.ToPix(bitMapInput); 
    var imgOut = PixConverter.ToPix(bitMapOutput);

    using (var page = ocr.Process(imgIn, rCurr, PageSegMode.SparseText))
    {
        SetTextBoxCurrent("Текущ: " + page.GetText());
    }

    using (var page2 = ocr.Process(imgOut, rMax, PageSegMode.SparseText))
    {
        SetTextBoxMax("Макс: " + page2.GetText());
    }
}
```

Result of OCR1:

[image]

Result of OCR2:

[image]